# Function require_once doesn't show the exception message according to the custom function

Tags: php

The function below doesn't seem to work correctly. In the function **load_module** I am using the `require()` function in PHP to get the file from **Modules** Folder.

What am trying to do is, check if file is in the modules folder, if its exist then run the `require_once()` function. When I try with the file on the modules folder its works great, then what I did was removed the file and then tried again it gave me this error:

> Warning: require_once(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\hoplate\admin\components\template.php on line 4

Whereas it should have showed this exception error message:

> There was an error, It seems that the moudle doesn't exist in it's location xxxx

**Function load_module**

```
function load_module( $_module_file, $require_once = true ) {
        if ( $require_once )
            if ( require_once( $_module_file ))
                require_once( $_module_file);
            else
                return "There was an error, It seems that the moudle doesn't exist in it's location $_module_file";
        else
            if( require( $_module_file ) )
                require( $_module_file );
            else 
                return "There was an error, It seems that the moudle doesn't exist in it's location $_module_file";
    }
```

**Function get_module**

```
/* Get Modules */
            function get_module( $_module_slug ){
                load_template( ADMIN_PATH . '/modules/' . $_module_slug . '.php');
            }
```

**More Information**
I have also tried using the `file_exists()` function but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So where are you checking to see if it exists? looks more like you're `require_oncing` it twice (which is pretty pointless)... and the equivalent `requiring` twice is likely to give you errors even if it does exist

Comment: Actually, it does make a point to me, if you see the function load_module, The PHP function require_once and require is based on the condition of $require_once = true which is passed onto the function load_module parameter.

Comment: No! READ YOUR CODE: `if ( require_once( $_module_file ))
                require_once( $_module_file);` and `if( require( $_module_file ) )
                require( $_module_file );
`

Comment: @NavneilNaicker, Mark is correct. As part of your conditional, it's going to call require_once, and if it finds the file, it's going to call it again, which is pointless. Additionally, where exactly is this all supposed to appear? You're returning strings, but I don't see them being echoed anywhere. If you need to suppress the warning just put @ in front of the function call

Comment: Sorry @MarkBaker, I understand what you are talking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

> require[_once] is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error

Your if check is not only returning false, but also causing a fatal error which stops execution, so it never gets to the `else`

You should either use `include` instead (which only causes a `WARNING`) or `file_exists` to check if the module exists... since you are handling the error yourself there is no benefit to using `require` over `include`. Also, just for better practice I would recommend throwing an exception instead of returning an error string.

Full code:

```
if ( file_exists( $_module_file ))
  include_once( $_module_file );
else
  throw new Exception("error...");
```

Or to simplify things, if you're ignoring WARNING level errors

```
if( !include_once( $_module_file ))
  throw new Exception("error...");
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone else bump into same issue. This is the working solution

```
<?php
    function load_module( $_module_file, $require_once = true ) {
        if ( $require_once )
            if( !file_exists ( $_module_file ))
                echo "<strong>There was an error</strong>, <br/> It seems that the module doesn't exist in it's location <b>$_module_file</b>";
            else 
                require_once( $_module_file );

        else
            if( !file_exists ( $_module_file ))
                echo "<strong>There was an error</strong>, <br/> It seems that the module doesn't exist in it's location <b>$_module_file</b>";
            else 
                require( $_module_file );
    }

    /* Get Modules */
    function get_module( $_module_slug ){
        load_module( ADMIN_PATH . '/modules/' . $_module_slug . '.php');
    }
?>
```